# Visual Studio 2019 - Cannot see the designer window - how to add xaml?

Tags: winforms, designer, vsix

I am working on a VSIX/WPF project someone else created at work and I just cannot see any designer window

[image]

- I checked the doc, and it says this error occurs when the class is not  at the top of the file, but it is
- I tried rebuilding the project
- I have that issue on all the components of that project

```
using EnvDTE;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SomeNameSpace.SomeWindow
{
   public partial class SomeWindow: Form
   {
      public SomeWindow()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         comboBoxSeverity.SelectedIndex = 1;
      }
```

[edit]

I found there was no xaml for some components. is it possible to add it ?

thanks for your help

Comment: You have a WinForms project, not WPF.

Comment: that does not tell me the source of the error. I found this warning : The parent file, 'SomeWindow.cs', for file '.....\SomeWindow.Designer.cs' cannot be found in the project file. yet the file is there

Comment: It was not meant to "tell you the source of the error", just to correct your statement about the UI framework you are using.

Comment: The error message is telling you that SomeWindow.cs is not in the project file .csproj extension. You can edit this file only if you right click the project and select unload project.

Comment: I noticed the code is generated "#region Windows Form Designer generated code" but generated by what ? some components have a xaml designer file, some dont

Comment: now I realize the project mixes wpf and windows forms...meh...still wonder why the designer is complaining

Comment: I seriously doubt that. You can host WPF controls in Windows Forms and vice versa but mixing Windows Forms and WPF Forms in one project????? One solution yes. I think you need to post a lot more code. Especially the project file. I'd really like to see that

Comment: it s a legacy soft that was passed through many hands. indeed mixing UI is dumb. I cant really post anything without heavy mods, it's company policy. I d better refactor these components